# QT GUI Real Time Update Via QThread (MoveToThread) & STD::Async

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11

I tried to draw 10 rectangle from each one of 10 threads. Using the QT MoveToThread style it worked fine (using Signal & Slot).
But instead MoveToThread when i tried to use the std::async, the competed rectangle shown (displayed) only after the program ends its execution. Till that time the GUI got hanged. I have mentioned the code logic of the program below. (posting the actual code takes too lenght). How to use the Signal & Slot concept when using std::async()?

**Code Logic**

```
1) class Process : Public QObject {  
       Q_Object     
       Process_slot {     
          emit Update_ui_signal //connected to Update_ui_slot of below class    
          }    
       Process_method {     
          emit Update_ui_signal //connected to Update_ui_slot of below class   
          }    
       }; 

2) class UpdateUI : Public QObject {   
        Q_Object     
        Update_ui_slot {    
           update ui    
          }    
       };
```

QT MoveToThread Code:

```
//here its working as expected   
//Real time update happen 
Process_object[10];thread_object[10];
Process_object[].movetothread(thread_object[])    
connect(call process_slot when thread_object start)    
thread_object[].start()
```

STD::Async Code:

```
//here the GUI got hanged and got the expected result after the execution finished
//Real time update not happening
std::future objF[10];
objF[] = std::async(std::launch::async, Process_method)
objF[].get();
```

STD::Thread Code:

```
//Behaved as same as the std::async
```

Please let me know if the "actual code"/"more information" needed.

Comment: Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html#processEvents